# scrollToTop is not working on jQuery(document).on('ready', function() {

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to load my `scrolltoTop()` function on dom ready, but the event is not firing. Can you please someone help me?

My code is here:

```
<button class="scroll-top">
<i class="fa fa-angle-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

:

```
"use strict";
function scrollToTop () {
  if ($('.scroll-top').length) {
    $(window).on('scroll', function (){
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
        $('.scroll-top').fadeIn();
      }
      else {
        $('.scroll-top').fadeOut();
      }
    });
    $('.scroll-top').on('click', function() {
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},1500);
      return false;
    });
  }
}
```

Here is my DOM ready function:

```
jQuery(document).on('ready', function() {
  (function ($) {
    scrollToTop ();
  })(jQuery);
});
```

Using Jquery version: **jquery-3.4.1.min.js**

Comment: pass as `$(window).scrollTop(0)`

Comment: `scrollToTop()` or `scrollTop()`?

Comment: is the `srcollToTop()` a custom function?

Comment: @randomSoul I have updated my code, Can you please check?

Comment: @dwpu I have updated my code, Can you please check?

Comment: @DevsiOdedra I have updated my code, Can you please check?

Comment: is your `scrollToTop` function in a separate file? If so, try to place you jQuery `ready` after the place the file is included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$(document).ready(function() {}`

```js
"use strict";

function scrollToTop() {
  console.log('Calling');
  if ($('.scroll-top').length) {
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
      console.log($(this).scrollTop());
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {

        $('.scroll-top').fadeIn();
      } else {
        $('.scroll-top').fadeOut();
      }
    });
    $('.scroll-top').on('click', function() {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
      }, 1500);
      return false;
    });
  }
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  scrollToTop();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="scroll-top">
   <i class="fa fa-angle-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

**See this demo. when you run script it will scroll to top**

```js
jQuery(document).on('ready', function() {

  $(window).scrollTop(0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="border:1px solid black;width:100px;height:150px;overflow:auto">
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.</div><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

From jquery [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) , from version 3.0

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

was replaced with

```
$(function() {
   // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

Maybe try:

```
$(function() {
   window.scrollTo(0,0);
});
```